# Storing a folder in a file with java

Tags: java

What would be the easier and safer way in JAVA to store a folder in a single file like zip, tar, rar, iso, etc? something like compressing and decompressing it. I don't really need compression, just putting the whole folder in a single file

I'm looking for a library that allows me to simply give it the path to the folder and obtain the file and the reverse process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [ZT-Zip](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-zip) on GitHub.

#### Compress a directory into a ZIP archive

```
ZipUtil.pack(new File("/tmp/demo"), new File("/tmp/demo.zip"));
```

#### Extract a ZIP archive

```
ZipUtil.unpack(new File("/tmp/demo.zip"), new File("/tmp/demo"));
```

The library supports a lot of other cool operations as well, including [existence checking](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-zip#check-if-an-entry-exists-in-a-zip-archive), [extracting a subset](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-zip#extract-an-entry-from-a-zip-archive-into-file-system) of a zip archive and [comparing](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-zip#compare-two-zip-archives-ignoring-timestamps-of-the-entries) zip archives.

Check out the [Readme](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-zip#zip---convenience-methods)